# Insert left-aligned text in split environment (mathtools isn't allowed)

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, split

As I say, I can't use mathtools package or anything else (because my teacher at the university doesn't allow it). I'm trying to write a text (a word, 'és', what means 'and', but it is irrelevant) to the left side. If I just write with a \text command, like this:

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    D\left(n\right) &= \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left[\frac{n}{m}\right] \geq \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left( \frac{n}{m} - 1 \right) = - n + n \sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{m} > \\
    &> n \log{\left(n+1\right)} - n > n \log n - n \\
    \text{és} \\
    D\left(n\right) &= \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left[ \frac{n}{n} \right] \leq\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m} < n\left(1 + \log n \right).
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

and the output is definitely not on the left:
[image: with text]

With amsmath's intertext command:

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    D\left(n\right) &= \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left[\frac{n}{m}\right] \geq \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left( \frac{n}{m} - 1 \right) = - n + n \sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{m} > \\
    &> n \log{\left(n+1\right)} - n > n \log n - n \\
    \intertext(és)
    D\left(n\right) &= \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left[ \frac{n}{n} \right] \leq\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m} < n\left(1 + \log n \right).
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

the result is another wrong output, because everything is on the left:

[image: what]

So, how to write a word to the left side without additional packages if two separate environment isn't an option because the equations are aligned to each other?

Comment: Could you place all before 'es' within `$$` and then 'es' and then the rest within `$$`? This would keep the 'es' on the left of the document and the maths in the middle.

Comment: And why don't you use `\intertext`?

Comment: @CooperCape there is a reason: the three equations are aligned at their equal or greater than signs.

Comment: @Bernard for some reason, if I use the \intertex command, all of these equations are aligned to the left side, and I just want the 'és' word to be on the left side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of `equation*`/`split` try to use `align*`. And, don't overuse `\left` and `\right` to auto-size parentheses.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
D(n)
    & = \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left[\frac{n}{m}\right] \geq \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left( \frac{n}{m} - 1 \right)
        = - n + n \sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{m} > \\
    & > n \log(n+1) - n > n \log n - n
\intertext{es}
    &= \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left[ \frac{n}{n} \right] \leq\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m} < n(1 + \log n).
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't mention it. :-)

Comment: I don't know why, but I have not tried align* instead of equation/split. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In plain TeX, we have `\eqalignno` (which expands to `\halign` in display) and `\noalign` for such cases:

```
$$\eqalignno{
D(n) & = \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left[n\over m\right] 
      \geq \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left({n\over m}-1 \right)
       = - n + n \sum_{m=1}^{n} {1\over m} > \cr
     & > n \log(n+1) - n > n \log n - n \cr
\noalign{és}
     & = \sum_{m=1}^n \left[n\over n\right] 
      \leq\sum_{m=1}^n {1\over m} < n(1+\log n).
}$$

\bye
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help @wipet but my code is in LaTeX. It is my fault, I don't write it anywhere.

Comment: @BenceLászló I understood that you are using LaTeX (from your WME). There is no your fault. I added my post only for sake of complexity i.e. "how to solve your problem when using plain TeX".

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities (plus the simple solution with `\shortintertext` from `mathtools`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  D\left(n\right) & = \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left[\frac{n}{m}\right] \geq \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left( \frac{n}{m} - 1 \right) = - n + n \sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{m} > \\
                  & > n \log{\left(n+1\right)} - n > n \log n - n \\
  \shortintertext{és}
  D\left(n\right) & = \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left[ \frac{n}{n} \right] \leq\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m} < n\left(1 + \log n \right).
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  D\left(n\right) & = \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left[\frac{n}{m}\right] \geq \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left( \frac{n}{m} - 1 \right) = - n + n \sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{m} > \\
                  & > n \log{\left(n+1\right)} - n > n \log n - n \\[-2.5ex]
  \intertext{és\vspace{-1.5ex}}
  D\left(n\right) & = \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left[ \frac{n}{n} \right] \leq\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m} < n\left(1 + \log n \right).
\end{align*}

\begin{flalign*}
  & & D\left(n\right) &= \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left[\frac{n}{m}\right] \geq \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left( \frac{n}{m} - 1 \right) = - n + n \sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{m} > & & \\
  & & &> n \log{\left(n+1\right)} - n > n \log n - n \\
  & \text{és}
  & D\left(n\right) &= \sum_{m=1}^{n} \left[ \frac{n}{n} \right] \leq\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m} < n\left(1 + \log n \right).
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, all of these suggestions are working! Unfortunately, I can't mark two replies as 'accepted'.

Comment: That's really unimportant. The aim was to show the many possibilities one has in such a situation. What puzzles me is why your teacher doesn't allow `mathtools`? It's just a (very useful) extension of `amsmath`.

Comment: He insists on his way. I don't know why (he behaves similar on his other subjects too), but I don't think he has a problem with it, just doesn't allow to use additional packages.

Comment: I can understand  he doesn't want additional packages which might cause problems, but in my opinion, he should insist on loading it in the place  of amsmath…